# How do I call this attribute to my if statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

This is my first post to Stackoverflow so I would appreciate any comments on how I presented the question/title as well as an answer to my actual question. I'm having trouble getting my if statement to work. Basically, I'm trying to give all cards a number value and a color value. I am having trouble getting the cardcolor attribute to my playerCards[] that i have dealt out. I put a line of ???????? marks where I'm having trouble. Furthermore, I'm not sure if dealing out my cards from a switch statement is the correct way to do this using an Enum is better.. Please help me! I'm new so be gentle (j/k)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;

namespace Drinking_Game_
{
    class Program
    {
    static string redOrBlack = "";
    static string highOrLow = "";
    static string pickASuit = "";
    static string yesOrNo = "";
    static int total = 0, count = 1;
    static int cardColorBlack = 1, cardColorRed = 0;
    static string cardSuit = "";
    static Random cardRandomizer = new Random();
    static string[] playerCards = new string[4];



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Title = "The Made up Game";
        Start();

    }
    static void Start()
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("So you wanna play a  game? Yes or No" );
            yesOrNo = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            if (yesOrNo.Equals("no")) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have to enter Yes or No");

            }
        } while (!yesOrNo.Equals("yes") ); //&& !yesOrNo.Equals("no")
        Console.WriteLine("Allright then lets play! Red or Black?");
        redOrBlack = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        //Console.ReadLine();
        Game();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Game()
    {
        playerCards[0] = Deal();
        Console.WriteLine(" You were dealt a {0}", playerCards[0]);
        ColorChoice();
    }

    static void ColorChoice()
    {


        if (????????????????????)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Give 2");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Take 2");
        }

    }

    static string Deal()
    {
        string Card = "";
        int cards = cardRandomizer.Next(1, 53);
        switch (cards)
        {
            case 1: Card = "Two of Diamonds"; total += 2; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 2: Card = "Three of Diamonds"; total += 3; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 3: Card = "Four of Diamonds"; total += 4; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 4: Card = "Five of Diamonds"; total += 5; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 5: Card = "Six of Diamonds"; total += 6; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 6: Card = "Seven of Diamonds"; total += 7; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 7: Card = "Eight of Diamonds"; total += 8; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 8: Card = "Nine of Diamonds"; total += 9; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 9: Card = "Ten of Diamonds"; total += 10; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 10: Card = "Jack of Diamonds"; total += 10; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 11: Card = "Queen of Diamonds"; total += 10; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 12: Card = "King of Diamonds"; total += 10; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 13: Card = "Ace of Diamonds"; total += 11; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 14: Card = "Two of Hearts"; total += 2; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 15: Card = "Three of Hearts"; total += 3; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 16: Card = "Four of Hearts"; total += 4; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 17: Card = "Five of Hearts"; total += 5; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 18: Card = "Six of Hearts"; total += 6; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 19: Card = "Seven of Hearts"; total += 7; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 20: Card = "Eight of Hearts"; total += 8; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 21: Card = "Nine of Hearts"; total += 9; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 22: Card = "Ten of Hearts"; total += 10; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 23: Card = "Jack of Hearts"; total += 10; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 24: Card = "Queen of Hearts"; total += 10; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 25: Card = "King of Hearts"; total += 10; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 26: Card = "Ace of Hearts"; total += 11; cardColorRed = 0;
                break;
            case 27: Card = "Two of Spades"; total += 2; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 28: Card = "Three of Spades"; total += 3; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 29: Card = "Four of Spades"; total += 4; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 30: Card = "Five of Spades"; total += 5; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 31: Card = "Six of Spades"; total += 6; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 32: Card = "Seven of Spades"; total += 7; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 33: Card = "Eight of Spades"; total += 8; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 34: Card = "Nine of Spades"; total += 9; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 35: Card = "Ten of Spades"; total += 10; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 36: Card = "Jack of Spades"; total += 10; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 37: Card = "Queen of Spades"; total += 10; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 38: Card = "King of Spades"; total += 10; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 39: Card = "Ace of Spades"; total += 11; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 40: Card = "Two of Clubs"; total += 2; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 41: Card = "Three of Clubs"; total += 3; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 42: Card = "Four of Clubs"; total += 4; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 43: Card = "Five of Clubs"; total += 5; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 44: Card = "Six of Clubs"; total += 6; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 45: Card = "Seven of Clubs"; total += 7; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 46: Card = "Eight of Clubs"; total += 8; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 47: Card = "Nine of Clubs"; total += 9; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 48: Card = "Ten of Clubs"; total += 10; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 49: Card = "Jack of Clubs"; total += 10; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 50: Card = "Queen of Clubs"; total += 10; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 51: Card = "King of Clubs"; total += 10; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            case 52: Card = "Ace of Clubs"; total += 11; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
            default: Card = "2 of Diamonds"; total += 2; cardColorBlack = 1;
                break;
        }
        return Card;
    }    


    }

}
```

Comment: You have stated that you are having trouble, but you haven't described what your *problem* is. I see the `??????` in your code, but what would you like there? What decision do you want your program to make at that point?

Comment: I would never create such a long `switch-case`, very bad design.

Comment: I would like for program to decide if the card is red to give 2 and the card is black to take 2

Comment: and instead of a switch-case statement what would you create?

Comment: @user2755779 it depends on your rule/data structure. `switch-case` can be considered as `external` switching while for example, a `Dictionary` can be considered as `internal` switching, there are many ways to do. Of course the point is how your data is structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your program design but it's beyond the scope of this answer to address them all. You're most likely running into problems because you're using one field to track whether a card is black and another to track whether it's red but you don't ever change their values. You would be better off combining them into a single field, then setting it appropriately when a new card is dealt.

```
private const int BLACK = 1;
private const int RED = 2;

private static int cardColor = 0;

...

string Card = "";
int cards = cardRandomizer.Next(1, 53);
switch(cards)
{
    case 1:
        Card = "Two of Diamonds"; total += 2; cardColor = RED;
        break;
...
}
```

This makes it easier to check the color later on:

```
if (cardColor == RED)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give 2");
}
else if(cardColor == BLACK)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Take 2");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unknown card color.");
}
```

Note that there are much better ways to write this type of program but this should work well enough for what you have.

Comment: Why not an Enum? Same with the card types, Diamond, Heart etc.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen An Enum would be ideal but they have all of their code in one file so I decided to stick with that theme.